# A problem occurred configuring project ':app'

Tags: react-native

Getting error when trying react-native run-android.I don't know why I'm getting this error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vector-icons'.
  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:classpath'.
     > Could not find any matches for com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.+ as no versions of com.android.tools.build:gradle are available.
```

android\build.gradle  is as follows.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is 
 installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
 }
}
```

gradle version: 3.3, 
plugin:2.2.3

Answer (score 1):

Change dependencies from:

`dependencies {
  implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:${safeExtGet('reactNativeVersion', '+')}"
}`

to:

`dependencies {
  compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:${safeExtGet('reactNativeVersion', '+')}"
}`

also change buildscript dependencies to use: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'`
and `maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/" }` instead of `google()`

So your ../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android/build.gradle should look like this:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/" }
    jcenter()
  }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

def safeExtGet(prop, fallback) {
    rootProject.ext.has(prop) ? rootProject.ext.get(prop) : fallback
}


android {
  compileSdkVersion safeExtGet('compileSdkVersion', 26)
  buildToolsVersion safeExtGet('buildToolsVersion', '26.0.3')

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion safeExtGet('minSdkVersion', 16)
    targetSdkVersion safeExtGet('targetSdkVersion', 26)
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }
  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:${safeExtGet('reactNativeVersion', '+')}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Upgrade `react-native-vector-icons: "^6.0.2"` in package.json
2. Then run `npm i react-native-vector-icons`
3. As a last step, `cd android && ./gradlew clean`.

Comment: This gives an error also:


`* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-vector-icons'.
> Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.`

Comment: @Ssey upgraded the react-native-vector-icons to 6.0.2. shows another error :`* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyApp1'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.jar`